# Integrate and InverseFunction

Tags: functions, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions, inverse, parameters

I solve an easy example to check that Mathematica can understand the difference between ArcTan and ArcTanh but as you see here I can't get Arctanh??!! Even I don't know why the inverse function is not working! thanks for helping

```
g = Integrate[1/((-(3/2))*x^2 + (3/2)*a*x+ b/2), x, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
Assuming[{a > 0, b >0},InverseFunction[g][x]]
```

a,b are positive.

Comment: `g` isn't a function; it's a symbolic expression. Try `g[x_] = Integrate[...]` instead (after `Clear[g]`);

Comment: My problem is the answer is Tanh[] but it gives me Tan[] !!!
tan(ix) = i tanh x

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the result in terms of the hyperbolic functions if you use FullSimplify:

```
Clear[g]
g[x_] = Assuming[
  a > 0 && b > 0,
  FullSimplify@Integrate[1/((-(3/2))*x^2 + (3/2)*a*x + b/2), x]
  ]
Assuming[
 a > 0 && b > 0,
 FullSimplify[InverseFunction[g][x]]
 ] // Normal
```

> -((4 ArcTanh[(a - 2 x)/Sqrt[a^2 + (4 b)/3]])/Sqrt[9 a^2 + 12 b])

> 1/6 (3 a + Sqrt[9 a^2 + 12 b] Tanh[1/4 Sqrt[9 a^2 + 12 b] x])

Comment: Thank you, so assuming will work here